# Viewing DTS packages on SSMS 2012

Tags: ssis, migration, ssms, dts, ssms-2012

We will be upgrading our SQL Server soon, but it is still using DTS components and thus I will be rewriting the packages so I can use all the new features of SSIS. I am trying to view the legacy DTS package in SSMS 2012 (I want to see what was previously done) but I simply cannot see them?

More info: I tried checking in the Management > legacy files and couldn't find anything.

Comment: There isn't a way that I know of, but you should be able to automatically convert them to 2008 SSIS packages, then open them in 2012 and manually convert anything you might need to (or view them then re-write yourself). Try using the free demo of 'xChange' here (note: I haven't used it, so I can't help with details, but rest assured it is Microsoft sponsored) http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/DTS-xChange

Comment: Actually, I think you could also download SSMS 2008 and view them there.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206991(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Luther, maybe try this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramoji/2008/10/16/how-to-open-dts-packages-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert on this, but hopefully that can point you in the right direction.  It doesn't *seem* that you need BIDS installed, but I wouldn't rule it out.

Comment: Nice!  Happy to help, and good luck with the rewrite.

Comment: PS. You should answer your own question here with the steps you took to fix it.  There are a couple other questions that are similar but I think there is value here that could help others. :) I would answer it myself, but I'm not positive on what steps worked for you in the end.  Will delete this comment later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution to being able to view Legacy DTS components.

1. Downloaded and install SSMS 2008 (install SP1 or higher) and choose the complete installation.
2. Download the DTS and Backwards compatibility components https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793
   I myself needed to install:
   SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi (This is the backwards compatibility component for a 64 bit system.)
3. Also select SQLServer2005_DTS.msi along with step 2 download.
4. Once installed you should be able to view the Legacy components.

Also, since I have been chasing this issue for a few days should I remember further steps that I took to install I will post here ASAP.